# Manipulating Data Frames through Pandas looping or Iterrows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, dictionary

I have a DataFrame

```
dict1={'layer': ['T&L', 'T&L', 'T&L', 'T&L', 'T&L', 'T&L', 'T&L'],
 'Object': ['Animals',
  'Animals',
  'Animals',
  'Animals',
  'Cars',
  'Cars',
  'Cars'],
 'Group': ['meat_eating',
  'meat_eating',
  'grass_eating',
  'grass_eating',
  'Fuel',
  'Fuel',
  'Battery'],
 'Attribute': ['dog', 'cat', 'goat', 'buffalo', 'Ford', 'Dodge', 'Tesla']}

df1=pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

which looks like this:

[First_dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeXRg.png)

I am trying to build a new DataFrame with IDs and trying to establish relationships using different keys and values from my first Dataframe.

My second Data Frame should look like this

[image: Expected_second_dataframe]

How do I use pandas with looping or Itertools to get results as the above data frame?

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow! Please don't post pictures of data, it is helpful for answering questions to be able to reproduce the data (both actual and expected). Your question is a bit unclear, could you describe exactly how you are hoping to transform the first DataFrame?

Comment: I am trying to map out "Layer"->  'Object', then 'Object'->'Group', then Group->'Attribute'

Comment: @nitman are your column names `Layer, Object, Group, Attribute` instead of `a,b,c,d`?

Comment: Yes, I have edited my first dataframe dict1={'layer': ['T&L', 'T&L', 'T&L', 'T&L', 'T&L', 'T&L', 'T&L'],
 'Object': ['Animals',
  'Animals',
  'Animals',
  'Animals',
  'Cars',
  'Cars',
  'Cars'],
 'Group': ['meat_eating',
  'meat_eating',
  'grass_eating',
  'grass_eating',
  'Fuel',
  'Fuel',
  'Battery'],
 'Attribute': ['dog', 'cat', 'goat', 'buffalo', 'Ford', 'Dodge', 'Tesla']}

Answer (score 1):

First we create a 'parent' df that tells us for each element its parent

```
dfp = df1.shift(axis=1)
```

`dfp` looks like this:

```
      layer  Object    Group    Attribute
--  -------  --------  -------  ------------
 0      nan  T&L       Animals  meat_eating
 1      nan  T&L       Animals  meat_eating
 2      nan  T&L       Animals  grass_eating
 3      nan  T&L       Animals  grass_eating
 4      nan  T&L       Cars     Fuel
 5      nan  T&L       Cars     Fuel
 6      nan  T&L       Cars     Battery
```

Next we `melt` df` and join to a melted dfp, and set the ID

```
df2 = df1.melt().join(dfp.melt(), lsuffix='', rsuffix='_p').drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop = True)
df2['ID'] = df2.index + 1
```

`df2`:

```
    variable    value         variable_p    value_p         ID
--  ----------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ----
 0  layer       T&L           layer         nan              1
 1  Object      Animals       Object        T&L              2
 2  Object      Cars          Object        T&L              3
 3  Group       meat_eating   Group         Animals          4
 4  Group       grass_eating  Group         Animals          5
 5  Group       Fuel          Group         Cars             6
 6  Group       Battery       Group         Cars             7
 7  Attribute   dog           Attribute     meat_eating      8
 8  Attribute   cat           Attribute     meat_eating      9
 9  Attribute   goat          Attribute     grass_eating    10
10  Attribute   buffalo       Attribute     grass_eating    11
11  Attribute   Ford          Attribute     Fuel            12
12  Attribute   Dodge         Attribute     Fuel            13
13  Attribute   Tesla         Attribute     Battery         14
```

Here now `value_p` has the parent of the elements in `value`

Now we map `value_p` to 'ID' using `value` as the key

```
df2['parent'] = df2['value_p'].map(df2[['value','ID']].set_index('value')['ID'])
df2 = (df2.drop(columns = ['variable_p', 'value_p'])
        .rename(columns = {'variable':'type','value':'name'})
    )
```

Final `df2`:

```
    type       name            ID    parent
--  ---------  ------------  ----  --------
 0  layer      T&L              1       nan
 1  Object     Animals          2         1
 2  Object     Cars             3         1
 3  Group      meat_eating      4         2
 4  Group      grass_eating     5         2
 5  Group      Fuel             6         3
 6  Group      Battery          7         3
 7  Attribute  dog              8         4
 8  Attribute  cat              9         4
 9  Attribute  goat            10         5
10  Attribute  buffalo         11         5
11  Attribute  Ford            12         6
12  Attribute  Dodge           13         6
13  Attribute  Tesla           14         7
```

Comment: Getting a for the last syntax when I try it on an another dataset "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"

Comment: @nitman pls post the offending part of the df

Comment: Is there a way i can send it directly

Comment: dict1={'layer': ['T&L', 'T&L', 'T&L', 'T&L', 'T&L', 'T&L', 'T&L','T&L'],
 'Object': ['Animals',
  'Animals',
  'Animals',
  'Animals',
  'Cars',
  'Cars',
  'Cars',
    'Animals'],
 'Group': ['meat_eating',
  'meat_eating',
  'grass_eating',
  'grass_eating',
  'Fuel',
  'Fuel',
  'Battery','Battery'],
 'Attribute': ['dog', 'cat', 'goat', 'buffalo', 'Ford', 'Dodge', 'Tesla','Kia']}

Comment: This is the dataframe, I am testing on. I am testing - 'Battery' Group and 'Kia' Attribute which are part of 'Animals' object here

Comment: @nitman Battery has two parents here (Cars and Animals), how do you decide?

Comment: Yes piterbarg Battery is part of both Cars and Animals. How do I create 2 batteries with different parent ID(i.e one for cars & one for animals)?

Comment: @nitman that sounds like a separate question :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71459601/reindexing-only-valid-with-uniquely-valued-index-objects-with-map-logic?noredirect=1#comment126305131_71459601 yes buddy have a look at the site!