# Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects 'with map logic'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, dictionary

My DataFrame:

```
dict1={'layer': ['T&L', 'T&L', 'T&L', 'T&L', 'T&L', 'T&L', 'T&L','T&L'],
 'Object': ['Animals',
  'Animals',
  'Animals',
  'Animals',
  'Cars',
  'Cars',
  'Cars',
    'Animals'],
 'Group': ['meat_eating',
  'meat_eating',
  'grass_eating',
  'grass_eating',
  'Fuel',
  'Fuel',
  'Battery','Battery'],
 'Attribute': ['dog', 'cat', 'goat', 'buffalo', 'Ford', 'Dodge', 'Tesla','Kia']}

df1=pd.DataFrame(dict1)


dfp = df1.shift(axis=1)

df2 = df1.melt().join(dfp.melt(), lsuffix='', rsuffix='_p').drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop = True)

df2['ID'] = df2.index + 1

df2['parent'] = df2['value_p'].map(df2[['value','ID']].set_index('value')['ID'])

df2 = (df2.drop(columns = ['variable_p', 'value_p'])
        .rename(columns = {'variable':'type','value':'name'})
    )
```

Error: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

I think I am getting this problem because

'Group':'Battery' is part of both objects: 'Animals', 'Cars'

But I want to get the expected output as below even with duplications

Expected output:

[image: expected DataFrame]

Comment: The reason this is happening is that there are two `Battery` items in `df2['value']`. Why is that?

Comment: Yes MyData Frame is something like that where Battery is part of both Animals and as well as Cars. But if you see my expected dataframe one of the Battery has parent of 2.0 which is animal and another battery has parent 3.0 which is cars. Similarly Attribute Kia has parent 6.0 battery and Attribute tesla as battery 8.0 as parent

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to tag 'Group' with the corresponding 'Object' before figuring out parents. Then eventually get rid of the Object tag in Group:

```
df1a = df1.copy()
df1a['Group'] = df1['Group'] + ':' + df1['Object'] # add the Object tag to group
dfp = df1a.shift(axis=1)
df2 = df1a.melt().join(dfp.melt(), lsuffix='', rsuffix='_p').drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop = True)
df2['ID'] = df2.index + 1
f2['parent'] = df2['value_p'].map(df2[['value','ID']].set_index('value')['ID'])
df2 = (df2.drop(columns = ['variable_p', 'value_p'])
        .rename(columns = {'variable':'type','value':'name'})
    )
df2['name'] = df2['name'].str.replace(':.+','') # get rid of the Object bit
```

`df2` looks like this:

```
    type       name            ID    parent
--  ---------  ------------  ----  --------
 0  layer      T&L              1       nan
 1  Object     Animals          2         1
 2  Object     Cars             3         1
 3  Group      meat_eating      4         2
 4  Group      grass_eating     5         2
 5  Group      Fuel             6         3
 6  Group      Battery          7         3
 7  Group      Battery          8         2
 8  Attribute  dog              9         4
 9  Attribute  cat             10         4
10  Attribute  goat            11         5
11  Attribute  buffalo         12         5
12  Attribute  Ford            13         6
13  Attribute  Dodge           14         6
14  Attribute  Tesla           15         7
15  Attribute  Kia             16         8
```